# How to use ./gradlew to run a specific tasks on a specific emulator?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, adb, android-testing, android-espresso

In a single computer, I have multiple simulators/devices that I can tell from adb devices.
192.168.56.102:5555
192.168.56.103:5555

**I want to run different tests on different devices at the same time by gradle command**, such as,

```
./gradlew -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=ccom.example.android.testapp1 connectedAutomationDebugAndroidTest --info

./gradlew -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=ccom.example.android.testapp2 connectedAutomationDebugAndroidTest --info
```

Is there any way I can add some parameter like "adb -s" to specify which device I want it run?

For now, **the only alternative way I have is** to use gradle run installApp task and then use 2 "adb -s" command to run 2 different sets of test each and connect with "&".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The OP made multiple questions, but with same context, hence below has multiple sections.

### Specify Task

To specify task, first find the tasks name:

```
chmod +x ./gradlew
./gradlew tasks
```

Then simply pass it, like:

```
./gradlew myCustomTask
```

Or, limit task to a specific project:

```
./gradlew :my-sub-project:myCustomTask
```

### Specify AVD <sup>(Android Virtual Device)</sup>

Passing AVD name to Gradle is **not** supported,
beside launching Emulator **not** being supported.

Hence the only way to specify AVD is to ensure that only that single AVD you desire is already running in Emulator (before you launch Gradle).

In other words, whatever AVD is already running in the Emulator will be used:

- for exmaple, if you want to  "re-run tests, but on another AVD, which has different Android version",
- you need to first wait until the previous tests finish,
- then close Emulator, and re-launch Emulator with the other AVD.

At least, passing AVD to Emulator is possible through CLI, like:

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -no-snapshot -no-snapshot-load -avd MyNameForAVD
```

Or in MacOS:

```
${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -no-snapshot -no-snapshot-load -avd MyNameForAVD
```